# Link error on compiling ghc 7.10.3 on SLES11

Tags: haskell, gcc, linker, ghc

I want to compile ghc 7.10.3 on a SLES11 instance since the downloaded binary doesn't work. Now I am getting link errors in the end:

```
/home/oswald/build/ghc-7.10.3/libraries/ghc-prim/dist-install/build/libHSghc-prim-0.4.0.0-8TmvWUcS1U1IKHT0levwg3-ghc7.10.3.so: undefined reference to `__sync_val_compare_and_swap_2'
/home/oswald/build/ghc-7.10.3/libraries/ghc-prim/dist-install/build/libHSghc-prim-0.4.0.0-8TmvWUcS1U1IKHT0levwg3-ghc7.10.3.so: undefined reference to `__sync_fetch_and_nand_2'
```

with a lot lines more. These seem to be GCC primitives. The installed gcc version on this machine is 4.3.4, which has primitives, but I did not find the _2 and _1 endings in the documentation (it uses variable arguments list as I understand it).

Any idea on how to solve this?

Comment: The `_2` suffix seems to be the operand size in bytes. My best guess is that your gcc is configured to by default target an architecture version that can't support these operations, like 486.

Comment: Hm, my gcc documentation says: "GCC will allow any integral scalar or pointer type that is 1, 2, 4 or 8 bytes in length.", so it should take basically any basic datatype. So just why have the suffixes be added?

Comment: GHC doesn't add the suffixes. (You can look in `libraries/ghc-prim/cbits/atomic.c`.) Test if `__sync_val_compare_and_swap` works on `uint16_t` for you at all, GHC aside.

Comment: Yup, seems that my gcc is too old for ghc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so I did install a newer gcc (4.9.3) locally and then the compilation of ghc was successful.